# Unity - Score stays on 1

Tags: collision, scoring, collect

Looking around in the forum. Finally, I decided to join in this big community for the support it provides!

I am creating this post because I am struggling in a 2D game that I am creating in Unity.

The game keeps scoring the number one once the play button is clicked. It increases the score once the food is collected, but the problem here is that once I click on "Play" button the score is already on "1" instead of "0".

Code in the following statement:

Scoring System

Collect C#

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 things:

1. Add a `Start()` function in Scoring System script.

```
private void Start(){
// This would make sure that score is 0 from the first frame
scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = " " + 0;
 }
```

2)Instead of directly running the code on trigger use tags, assign the tag of **Player** to your player gameObject, then add this code.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
      if(collision.tag == "Player"){
        ScoringSystem.theScore += 1;

      // Destroy(collision.gameObject);
      }
    }
```